# Best way to write an If statement in Python with a queryset that is out of index?

Tags: python, django, if-statement

Hey guys I'm trying to do a simple if statement in Python and I get an error any time I try to do a comparison between a queryset that is empty.

What's the best way to write this code so that it doesn't give me an error if there's no fields in the check variable?

If check comes up empty, then I get an error when I run the if(check[0].username == None) statement.

Thanks!

Here's my code:

```
def upvote(request):
    postID = request.POST.get("postID")
    currentUser = request.POST.get("currentUser")
    username = request.POST.get("username")
    query = NewPost.objects.get(id = postID)
    check = Vote.objects.filter(postID = postID) & Vote.objects.filter(username = currentUser)
    if(check[0].username == None):
        query.rating = query.rating +1
        query.save()
        query2 = User.objects.get(username = username)
        query2.userRanking = query2.userRanking +1
        query2.save()
        new = Vote.objects.create(postID = postID, username = currentUser)
        new.save()
        pyautogui.hotkey('f5')
        return render(request)
    else:
        pyautogui.hotkey('f5')
        return render(request)
```

Comment: Instead, why not use [error/exception handling](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) for the error? What error do you get?  This is a great, and relatively straightforward, case to try it out. (sorry, no pun intended).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to use `len()` function to check whether there are any elements inside the `check` variable

Example:

```
def upvote(request):
    postID = request.POST.get("postID")
    currentUser = request.POST.get("currentUser")
    username = request.POST.get("username")
    query = NewPost.objects.get(id = postID)
    check = Vote.objects.filter(postID = postID) & Vote.objects.filter(username = currentUser)
    if (len(check) > 0):
        if(check[0].username == None):
            query.rating = query.rating +1
            query.save()
            query2 = User.objects.get(username = username)
            query2.userRanking = query2.userRanking +1
            query2.save()
            new = Vote.objects.create(postID = postID, username = currentUser)
            new.save()
            pyautogui.hotkey('f5')
            return render(request)
        else:
            pyautogui.hotkey('f5')
            return render(request)
```

Comment: Looks like there is an issue with the `request` variable

Comment: Please consider approving the answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to do is to use [`exists()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists) method, because it will make minimum DB query to get you the result(True or False). For example:

```
check = Vote.objects.filter(postID = postID, username = currentUser)
if check.exists():
   if username == None: # no need to use check[0].username, because they are the same thing.
```